# Unique set of difference between nearest numbers in permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If we take the permutations of $n$ elements, e.g. for $n=3$:

$$123,132,213,231,312,321$$

and consider for each one the sequence of absolute differences $|\pi_{i+1} - \pi_i|$:

$$11,21,12,12,21,11$$

and group by the largest absolute difference $k$:

$$\{11\times 2\}, \{12\times 2, 21\times 2\}$$

we find that the size of each group (here $2, 4$) has no simple recurrence:

$$\begin{eqnarray}T(n,1)&=&2 & \textrm{for }n>1\\
T(n,k)&=&0 & \textrm{for }n\leqslant k\\
T(n,k)&=&2(n-1)! & \textrm{for }n=k+1, n>1\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

This is [OEIS A064482](https://oeis.org/A064482).

If we instead ask about the *distinct* sequences in each group (for $n=3$ that's $1, 2$) we get:

$$\{1\}\\
\{11\}, \{12,21\}\\
\{111\}, \{121,212\},\{321, 311, 131, 232, 123, 113\}\\
\cdots$$

or looking just at how many there are:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
1\; \\
1\;&2\;\\
1\;&2\;&6\;\\
1\;&7\;&24\;&22\;\\
1\;&8\;&36\;&110\;&112\;\\
1\;&20\;&140\;&457\;&900\;&648\\
1\;&25\;&328\;&990\;&4018\;&5834\;&4592
\end{eqnarray}$$

The table is not in OEIS, and nor is the second column or the diagonal. What can be said about it?

Comment: Do I interpret the question correctly that $F(n,k)$ is the number of sequences with maximal element $k$ that occur as sequence of absolute differences in at least one permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, thank you for comment! English is not my native, so I don't correctly understand you. My question was edited for better understanding.

Comment: Hope that's easier to understand. For what it's worth, the recurrence you give for A064482 is not in OEIS. Perhaps you could add it?